# Recovering from HTTP I/O error

Tags: http, tcp, network-programming, tomcat6, ioexception

We have exposed some REST APIs. We see IOExceptions few times on the server. We are not sure how do we recover from them.

Kind of I/O errors that we see are

1. Client timed out - We sent client_timed_out http error code and client retry. This works well.
2. Data is invalid. An e.g. that we see is "Invalid CRLF". Either this is be a client bug or somewhere something went wrong on the TCP/IP stack.

Do you think this could happen on TCP/IP level? If yes, shouldnt Http protocol have an error code that server can send to client and client can choose to retry the request.

Exception stack trace

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid CRLF
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.parseCRLF(ChunkedInputFilter.java:364)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.doRead(ChunkedInputFilter.java:145)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:308)
   at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:287)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:374)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.readByte(InputBuffer.java:300)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:108)
   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:66)
   at java.util.zip.CheckedInputStream.read(CheckedInputStream.java:42)
   at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:247)
   at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:239)
   at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:142)
   at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:58)
   at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:67)
   at org.restlet.engine.application.DecodeRepresentation.getDecodedStream(DecodeRepresentation.java:142)
   at org.restlet.engine.application.DecodeRepresentation.getStream(DecodeRepresentation.java:212)
   at com.inlogy.server.ingraph.service.apis.resource.DocumentHashMapResource.post(DocumentHashMapResource.java:57)
   at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:380)
```

Comment: Why don't you include the verbatim text of each error? (Probably best to format it as code, e.g. using Ctrl-K.)

Comment: Sure. I have attached the error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's something wrong with the [chunked transfer coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) of some incoming data. Presumably there's either a problem with the client, or a proxy somewhere along the way has gone amuck.